# Application crashes when searching data from listview using filterable

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-asynctask

I try to write an application for a library. I have an activity, where I see all books in stock. I use listView, and baseAdapter. All information are saved in a database.

**onCreate in Activity:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crown_library_details);

    // INITIALIZATION VALUE
    member = (Member) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(IntentExtra.MEMBER.toString());
    book = (Book) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(IntentExtra.BOOK.toString());
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author);
    title.setText(book.getTitle());
    author.setText(book.getAuthor());
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            bookShopArrayList = backend.getAllShopOfBookId(book.getBookID());
            cart = backend.getCart(member.getMemberID());
            if (member.isShop())
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.SHOP);
            else
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.MEMBER);
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.addListener(CrownLibraryDetails.this);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void list) {
            listView.setAdapter(bookShopShopEditionAdapter);
        }
    }.execute();

    // MENU
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_crown_library);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (member.isShop()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CrownLibraryDetails.this, BookDetailsForShop.class);
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.BOOK_SHOP.toString(), bookShopShopEditionAdapter.getItem(i));
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.PREVIOUS_ACTiVITY.toString(), IntentExtra.CROWN_LIBRARY_DETAILS.toString());
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.MEMBER.toString(), member);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CrownLibraryDetails.this, BookDetailsForMember.class);
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.BOOK_SHOP.toString(), bookShopShopEditionAdapter.getItem(i));
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.MEMBER.toString(), member);
                intent.putExtra(IntentExtra.PREVIOUS_ACTiVITY.toString(), IntentExtra.CROWN_LIBRARY_DETAILS.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String s) {
            if (member.isShop())
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.SHOP);
            else
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.MEMBER);
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.addListener(CrownLibraryDetails.this);
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            listView.setAdapter(bookShopShopEditionAdapter);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String s) {
            if (member.isShop())
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.SHOP);
            else
                bookShopShopEditionAdapter = new BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(CrownLibraryDetails.this,
                        bookShopArrayList, member.getMemberID(), book.getBookID(), AccessType.MEMBER);
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.addListener(CrownLibraryDetails.this);
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            listView.setAdapter(bookShopShopEditionAdapter);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**my baseAdpater:**

```
 public class BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ArrayList<BookShop> bookShopsList;
ArrayList<BookShop> searchStoreOrEdition;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
long memberID;
long bookID;
AccessType accessType;
Shop _shop;

private Backend backend = BackendFactory.getInstance(context);

public BookShop_ShopEditionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BookShop> list, long memberID, long bookID, AccessType accessType) {
    this.bookShopsList = list;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    this.memberID = memberID;
    this.bookID = bookID;
    this.accessType = accessType;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults fr = new FilterResults();

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    if (constraint.equals("")) {
                        searchStoreOrEdition = bookShopsList;
                    } else {
                        for (BookShop book_shopItem : bookShopsList) {
                            if (backend.getShopToID(book_shopItem.getShopID()).getShopName()
                                    .toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                                searchStoreOrEdition.add(book_shopItem);
                            else if (book_shopItem.getEdition().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                                searchStoreOrEdition.add(book_shopItem);
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void avoid) {
                }
            }.execute();


            fr.count = searchStoreOrEdition.size();
            fr.values = searchStoreOrEdition;
            return fr;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null) {
                bookShopsList = (ArrayList<BookShop>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}

public interface StoreEditionAdapterListener {[...]}

private ArrayList<StoreEditionAdapterListener> listListener = new ArrayList<>();

public void addListener(StoreEditionAdapterListener aListener){[...]}

private void sendListenerBuy(BookShop item, int position) {[...]}

private void sendListenerDelete(BookShop item, int position) {[...]}

@Override
public int getCount() {[...]}

@Override
public BookShop getItem(int position){[...]}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {[...]}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout layoutItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_book_shop_shop_edition_adapter, parent, false);
    } else {
        layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    final TextView shop = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.shop);
    final TextView edition = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.edition);
    final TextView format = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.format);
    final TextView state = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.state);
    final TextView price = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.price);

    ImageView deleteIcon = (ImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    ImageView buyexpressicon = (ImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.buyExpressIcon);
    TextView buyexpress = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.buyExpress);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            _shop = new Shop(backend.getShopToID(bookShopsList.get(position).getShopID()));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void avoid) {
            shop.setText(_shop.getShopName());

        }
    }.execute();


    edition.setText(bookShopsList.get(position).getEdition());
    format.setText(bookShopsList.get(position).getFormat().toString());
    state.setText(bookShopsList.get(position).getState().toString());
    price.setText(String.format("%s$", bookShopsList.get(position).getPriceBook()));

    if (accessType.equals(AccessType.DIRECTOR_DELETE)) {//Director
        deleteIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buyexpress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buyexpressicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (accessType.equals(AccessType.SHOP)) {
        buyexpress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buyexpressicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        deleteIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else
        deleteIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Click
    buyexpressicon.setTag(position);
    buyexpressicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            sendListenerBuy(bookShopsList.get(position), position);
        }
    });

    deleteIcon.setTag(position);
    deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            sendListenerDelete(bookShopsList.get(position), position);
        }
    });

    return layoutItem;
}
```

}

At the time, I writte in the searchBar, and I call the function filter of my baseAdapter. The application stops running, without say anyting.

```
01-21 08:50:51.512 19914-19914/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-21 08:50:51.556 19914-19920/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-21 08:50:51.800 19914-19914/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-21 08:50:51.804 19914-19914/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-21 08:50:51.804 19914-19914/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18302: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-21 08:50:51.804 19914-19914/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-21 08:50:51.808 19914-19914/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-21 08:50:51.808 19914-19914/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18306: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-21 08:50:51.808 19914-19914/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 780: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 782: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-21 08:50:51.844 19914-19914/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-21 08:50:51.888 19914-19917/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 195K, 3% free 10932K/11207K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 20ms
01-21 08:50:51.944 19914-19914/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-21 08:50:51.944 19914-19914/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb80b6c50, tid 19914
01-21 08:50:51.956 19914-19914/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-21 08:50:51.956 19914-19914/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-21 08:50:52.024 19914-19914/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-21 08:50:52.036 19914-19914/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-21 08:50:52.300 19914-19914/? D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb80c93b8): name, size, mSize = 4, 2200, 2200
01-21 08:50:52.356 19914-19914/? D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb80c7fe0): name, size, mSize = 5, 2200, 4400
01-21 08:50:52.540 19914-19914/? D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb80e30f0): name, size, mSize = 11, 4096, 8496
01-21 08:50:52.588 19914-19914/com.example.lilo.ebookstore I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: don't you have any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Its not required to set adapter all over again in QueryTextListener. If your filter is working, you don't have to do anything except this :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String s) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String s) {
            bookShopShopEditionAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        bookShopShopEditionAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also you don't need to run an asynctask in your filter to do filtering.

Example for using filter in listview :

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html